# meta_query not working with the_content()

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have two custom post types: `events` and `venue`. I'm trying to query related events into the venue page. I have the related variable stored in a custom field for `venues` and the `events` related value in `the_content()`. Can I pull `the_content()` from events before I run `new WP_Query()` and if so why isn't this working?

```
$args_up = array(
    'post_type'         => 'events', 
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    'paged'             => $paged, 
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'       => the_content(),
            'value'     => $related_venue_variable,
            'compare'   => '=='
        )
    )   
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) echoes data to the page so essentially your query looks like:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => '',
        'value'   => $related_venue_variable,
        'compare' => '=='
     )
)
```

You want [`get_the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) to return a string that you can pass along through the query.

However, having the post content as a meta key doesn't make any sense. For one, [that key only holds 225 characters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta). Given that you may be storing the key from another post in the post content of a second post, that may not be a problem, but any filters applied on the post content will be as those can alter the content retrieved. In short, what you are doing is a bad, bad idea.

Now I'm guessing, but I think this is close to what you want to achieve:

```
if( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        $args_up = array(
            'post_type'         => 'events', 
            'posts_per_page'    => 20,
            'paged'             => $paged, 
            'meta_query'        => array(
                array(
                    'key'       => $post->post_content,
                    'value'     => $related_venue_variable,
                    'compare'   => '=='
                )
            )
        );

        $eq = new WP_Query( $args_up );
    }
}
```

But it's still a bad idea to save a key as post content. You'd be better off saving it as custom meta in both posts. Of course, there might be a better way to do this all around if I knew exactly how it all went together.

Comment: thanks for the response. Your suggestion did not work but it got me thinking in the right direction thank you.